# Qt QML Listview positionViewAtIndex not working

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I have a vertical Listview and when i click an item i will display horizontal Listview. The question is that when i click 2 nd item i should display 2nd item on horizontal Listview. Here it is my implementation:

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
id: root
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")

StackView {
    id: rootStackView
    anchors.fill: parent
    initialItem: verListView

}

VListview {
    id: verListView
    onListItemClicked: {
        rootStackView.push(horListView)
        horListView.init(index)
    }
}

HListView {
    id: horListView
    visible: false
}
}
```

VListview.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0


Page {
id: root

signal listItemClicked(var index)


ListView {

    id: listView
    anchors.fill: parent
    Layout.fillWidth: true

    model: ListModel {
        ListElement {
            name: "Bill Smith"
            number: "555 3264"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "John Brown"
            number: "555 8426"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "Sam Wise"
            number: "555 0473"
        }
    }

    delegate: Component {
        id: contactDelegate
        Item {
            MouseArea {
               anchors.fill: parent
               onClicked: {
                   console.log("aaa")
                   root.listItemClicked(index)
               }
            }
            width: listView.width; height: 40
            Column {
                Text { text: '<b>Name:</b> ' + name }
                Text { text: '<b>Number:</b> ' + number }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

HListview.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0


Page {

function init(index) {
    console.log(index)
    horizontalListView.currentIndex = index;
    horizontalListView.positionViewAtIndex(index, ListView.Beginning)
}

ListView {
    id: horizontalListView

    anchors.fill: parent
    orientation: ListView.Horizontal
    model: ListModel {
        ListElement {
            name: "Bill Smith"
            number: "555 3264"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "John Brown"
            number: "555 8426"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "Sam Wise"
            number: "555 0473"
        }
    }
    snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
    delegate: Component {
        id: contactDelegate
        Item {

            width: horizontalListView.width; height: 40
            Column {
                Text { text: '<b>Name:</b> ' + name }
                Text { text: '<b>Number:</b> ' + number }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

[image: VerticalListView]

HorizontalListView

[image: HListView]

I am clicking 2nd and 3 rd items but it display always first item. Anybody faced the issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: It will work as expected if you had more items, it will bring the selected item to the top of the view only if there are enough items behind it to fill the view. If you drag the last item to the top of the view it will bounce back and return because you are out of view bounds

Comment: You mean 3 items is not enough? If yes i don't think so, because in my project model has 60 item but there it is still not working

Comment: Looks like you cannot call `positionViewAtIndex` when the StackView is still [busy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html#busy-prop) (but Qt doc says nothing about this). Try to call `horListView.init(index)` after the Transition finished.

Comment: ```listView.positionViewAtIndex(index, ListView.Beginning)
```  works after transition. But i need to custom solution to implement what i need

Comment: Just add `highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange` to your original code and you got the correct item highlighted in the horizontal list. Can't say for sure if it's a bug or not. `ListView` tends to be a little bit (more) bugged when used in horizontal orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `width` of `horizontalListView` is wrongly set.

**HListview.qml**

```
ListView {
    id: horizontalListView

    //        anchors.fill: parent
    height: 40    <== fix the height
    width: root.width  <== width of the hview must be same size as that of root window.
    orientation: ListView.Horizontal
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

Explanation: If positioning the view at index would cause empty space to be displayed at the beginning or end of the view, the view will be positioned at the boundary.

Comment: Component.onCompleted is called when app is loading, even you didn't click list item. Secondly you always display item which is in position 2.

Comment: Sorry for that. I was practicing with the code must have copied the previous version. Edited the answer.

Comment: It is ok, but do i need to call positionViewAtIndex method?

Comment: The code remains the same. Just change the above lines in your code. Everything else seems good.

Comment: But it works perfect but it displays third element instead of first one?Did you click first element?

Comment: You want the same element to be displayed that was clicked, right ? Isn't above correction doing that ?

Comment: Yes i want to display the clicked item on Horizontal listview, but it is not working 100%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132497/discussion-between-nakhmedov-and-ansh-kumar).